# textbox in winforms with sunken border

Tags: winforms

How do i set Border properties on a TextBox Control in Winforms so that It displays sunken borders?
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: isn't that the default?  do you want it to look like the example 'Form3' in this link: http://www.startvbdotnet.com/controls/textbox.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the Microsoft Forms textbox Control to your toolbox.

[alt text http://img262.imageshack.us/img262/2989/28550946.png](http://img262.imageshack.us/img262/2989/28550946.png)

Answer (score 2):

Unusual request.  But you can do it by selectively disable the theming for the control.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class SunkenTextBox : TextBox {
  protected override void CreateHandle() {
    base.CreateHandle();
    SetWindowTheme(this.Handle, "", "");
  }
  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("uxtheme.dll")]
  private static extern void SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hWnd, string appname, string idlist);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` call from your Program.cs file.

Comment: doesn't seem to work... do I need to do something extra?
`EDIT`: got it working now.... the change is visible until you run your app.